# Записать значение из БД SQL в переменную

Tags: android, sql, база-данных

Мне нужно записать полученное по _id из БД значение (таблице кроме _id еще четыре колонки), после чего записать его в переменную
_id тоже определяется исходя из получаемой переменной
Мой код:

```
public int getCount (){
                Intent position = getIntent();
                int positionValue = position.getIntExtra("head", 0);
                String num_id = "_id=" + positionValue;
                db = sqlHelper.open();
                Cursor cursor = db.query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE,
                        new String[] {DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID, COLUMN_COUNTP},
                        DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID + " = ?", new String[] { num_id }, null, null, null,
                        COLUMN_COUNTP);
               int cnt = cursor.getCount();
               cursor.close();
               return cnt;
            }
```

Но это не работает

Comment: Обожаю такие вопросы, напоминает вопрос типа: *мне надо купить мяса и потом скормить его собаке - помогите!* Неужели трудно разложить свой вопрос на 2 части? 1) Купить мясо 2) Скормить его собаке - неужели трудно понять что одно от другого мало зависит? Кого колышет, что ТС собирается делать с `_id`? Получить его из БД - это одна задача, а вторая записать его значение - как это связано друг с другом и почему это один вопрос? Одним из важных свойств человеческого интеллекта является умение декомпозировать задачи на несколько составных частей, не находите?

Comment: Очень поэтично! Тогда по приоритетам: как записать полученное значение в переменную? Буду благодарен менее лиричному ответу, по-возможности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
       int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ID));
       //blah-blah
    } 
}
```